# Looping through data and passing it to a chart

Tags: javascript, json, apexcharts

I have an array of data that I'm using to plot a Line Chart. I'm using ApexCharts.

```js
let testData = [
  {
    cell_id: 5833307,
    datetime: ["2019-05-07 11:28:16.406795+03", "2019-05-07 11:28:38.764628+03", "2019-05-07 12:18:38.21369+03", "2019-05-07 12:33:47.889552+03", "2019-05-08 08:45:51.154047+03"],
    rsrq: ["108", "108", "108", "108", "109"]
  },
  {
    cell_id: 2656007,
    datetime: ["2019-07-23 15:29:16.572813+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:16.71938+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:16.781606+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:50.375931+03", "2019-07-23 15:30:01.902013+03"],
    rsrq: ["120", "119", "116", "134", "114"]
  }
];

let datasetValue = [];

for( let x=0; x<testData.length; x++ )
{
  datasetValue =
    { 
    chart: {
      height: 380,
      width: "100%",
      type: "line"
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'smooth',
      width: 1.5,
    },
    markers: {
      size: 4,
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      position: 'top'
    },  
    series: [
      {
        name: testData[x].cell_id,
        data: testData[x].rsrq
      }
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: testData[x].datetime,
      title: {
        text: "Date"
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: {
        text: "RSSI"
      }
    }
  }                
}
            
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#signal"), datasetValue);

chart.render();
```

```html
<div id="signal"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

So I take my JSON array, loop it in a `for` loop to obtain my datasets. I define an array variable `datasetValue` which i assign the looped data and pass it to my chart instance: `new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#rssi-signal"), datasetValue);`

What is happening is only the last array object is being passed meaning there's something I'm missing/not passing to get all my data.

Comment: You probably mean to `push` your data to your array rather than overwriting it with `datasetValue =`. Probably best to add to your question what `datasetValue` should look like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restructure the testData by grouping series and categories

```
let series = [];
let categories = [];

for (let x = 0; x < testData.length; x++) {
  series.push({
    name: testData[x].cell_id,
    data: testData[x].rsrq
  });
  categories.concat(testData[x].datetime);
}
```

```js
let testData = [{
    cell_id: 5833307,
    datetime: ["2019-05-07 11:28:16.406795+03", "2019-05-07 11:28:38.764628+03", "2019-05-07 12:18:38.21369+03", "2019-05-07 12:33:47.889552+03", "2019-05-08 08:45:51.154047+03"],
    rsrq: ["108", "108", "108", "108", "109"]
  },
  {
    cell_id: 2656007,
    datetime: ["2019-07-23 15:29:16.572813+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:16.71938+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:16.781606+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:50.375931+03", "2019-07-23 15:30:01.902013+03"],
    rsrq: ["120", "119", "116", "134", "114"]
  }
];

let series = [];
let categories = [];


for (let x = 0; x < testData.length; x++) {
  series.push({
    name: testData[x].cell_id,
    data: testData[x].rsrq
  });
  categories = categories.concat(testData[x].datetime);
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#signal"), {
  chart: {
    height: 380,
    width: "100%",
    type: "line"
  },
  stroke: {
    curve: 'smooth',
    width: 1.5,
  },
  markers: {
    size: 4,
  },
  legend: {
    show: true,
    position: 'top'
  },
  series: series,
  xaxis: {
    categories: categories,
    title: {
      text: "Date"
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: {
      text: "RSSI"
    }
  }
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<div id="signal"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are declaring an array outside the forloop

```
let datasetValue = { 
    chart: {
      height: 380,
      width: "100%",
      type: "line"
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'smooth',
      width: 1.5,
    },
    markers: {
      size: 4,
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      position: 'top'
    },  
    series: [],
    xaxis: {
      categories: [],
      title: {
        text: "Date"
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: {
        text: "RSSI"
      }
    }
  };
```

Inside for loop you should do

```
    datasetValue.series.push(
          {
            name: testData[x].cell_id,
            data: testData[x].rsrq
          });
    datasetValue.xaxis.categories.push(testData[x].datetime);
```

**You should push the value inside the array instead of reassigning it in each iteration**

Comment: hi Vivek. Thanks for your input. Had actually tried pushing my chart definitions as you suggest but getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Comment: @suo 
Hi suo, just checked the apexcharts and you should do this, please check the edited answer

Answer (score 2):

The first  mistake you are trying to do is defining the "datasetValue" as an array variable.

```js
datasetValue = yourdata; //wrong in case of pushing data into array
```

You are trying to assign an object to array variable that contains only last results due to looping and assignment.
Instead, use push method of array to push the data into an array.

```js
datasetValue.push(yourdata); //correct way to push data to array
```

So, there is no use to define "datasetValue" as array.

To achieve your objective you can apply loop with following

```js
var datasetValue;
var series = [];
var categories = [];

for(let x=0; x<testData.length;x++) {
series.push({
    name: testData[x].cell_id,
    data: testData[x].rsrq
});
categories.concat(testData[x].datetime);
}

datasetValue = { 
    chart: {
      height: 380,
      width: "100%",
      type: "line"
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'smooth',
      width: 1.5,
    },
    markers: {
      size: 4,
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      position: 'top'
    },  
    series,
    xaxis: {
      categories,
      title: {
        text: "Date"
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: {
        text: "RSSI"
      }
    }
  };

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#signal"), datasetValue);

chart.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

I move your for loop after datasetValue definition to add only series to it, and also change `xaxis`

```
for( let x=0; x<testData.length; x++ )
{
    datasetValue.series.push({
        name: testData[x].cell_id,
        data: testData[x].rsrq
    })
}
```

```js
let testData = [
  {
    cell_id: 5833307,
    datetime: ["2019-05-07 11:28:16.406795+03", "2019-05-07 11:28:38.764628+03", "2019-05-07 12:18:38.21369+03", "2019-05-07 12:33:47.889552+03", "2019-05-08 08:45:51.154047+03"],
    rsrq: ["108", "108", "108", "108", "109"]
  },
  {
    cell_id: 2656007,
    datetime: ["2019-07-23 15:29:16.572813+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:16.71938+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:16.781606+03", "2019-07-23 15:29:50.375931+03", "2019-07-23 15:30:01.902013+03"],
    rsrq: ["120", "119", "116", "134", "114"]
  }
];

let datasetValue = 
    { 
    chart: {
      height: 380,
      width: "100%",
      type: "line"
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'smooth',
      width: 1.5,
    },
    markers: {
      size: 4,
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      position: 'top'
    },  
    series: [
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: testData[0].datetime,
      title: {
        text: "Date"
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: {
        text: "RSSI"
      }
    }
  }
  
for( let x=0; x<testData.length; x++ )
{
    datasetValue.series.push({
        name: testData[x].cell_id,
        data: testData[x].rsrq
      })
}
  
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#signal"), datasetValue);

chart.render();
```

```html
<div id="signal"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Comment: hi Kamil. Thanks for your input. This works, though the only question would be why pass the categories as:  `testData[0].datetime`. because now the X-axis will only have data from the array's first object only. for the datetime property

Comment: It is more fundamental problem I think - to write multi-series data in one chart they need to have same domain (same x-axis dates/points) - so your input `datetime` for both series need to be the same (in your case their are different  - so the problem is in data itself)